# Android ContentProvider Uri Matching

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I am trying to create a content provider where the key contains forward slash "/". I searched about it for quite a while but there is no place/example illustrating it.

**content://com.lily.provider/items/***

General example, which I understand: 
**content://com.lily.provider/items/ab**

What I want to do: my key is a string with "/"
**content://com.lily.provider/items/a/b**
where a/b is the item id, which is in the same position as ab.

My question:

1. will content://com.lily.provider/items/a/b be matched to content://com.lily.provider/items/* ? why is that?
2. are there any work-around I could use to solve the problem

Comment: "/" is a forward slash, not a backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will content://com.lily.provider/items/a/b be matched to content://com.lily.provider/items/* ? why is that?

Yes, it will match. The asterisk `*` means "match any characters, including slashes".

> Are there any work-around I could use to solve the problem

If you want to match known prefixes, then you can just add more entries to your URI matcher (in this order):

- `content://com.lily.provider/items/a/*`
- `content://com.lily.provider/items/b/*`
- `content://com.lily.provider/items/*`

If you insist on having slashes in the data, then you should [URI-encode slashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters) that aren't being used as path separators to `%2f`.

Otherwise, I'm not sure what the problem is.  The "`/items/a/b`" URI will match your original pattern as desired, and then you can parse the path component of the URI as you wish.